# Loopback Model Remove attribute or Property before save

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I have been trying to wrap around my head with this for some time now.

I want to remove a certain attribute or property of a model before saving.

So far I am trying to catch the instance using Loopback's operational hook [before save](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Operation-hooks.html#before-save).

```
   MyModel.observe('before save', function(ctx, next){

      if (ctx.instance) {
         ctx.instance.removeProperty = undefined; 
      } else {
         ctx.data.removeProperty = undefined;    
      }

      next();

   });
```

Not sure why the above code is not working, by setting the attribute as `undefined` but you can set any other value to other properties.

UPDATE: The code above was actually working. But I have the problem with the instances which already has that attribute I want to remove.

Comment: use delete operator to remove property from object..!!

Comment: yes I have tried `delete ctx.instance.removeProperty;`. But just realized that the issue is with existing instances which already has the property.. it won't remove it.

Comment: i found that sometimes loopback gives you some kind of json type function, not the json object. you can see variable's holding functions when you debug them. at that time, you can stringify them and parse them again, then it will work

Answer (score 2):

In Loopback version 3,

In case of `ctx.data`

```
delete ctx.data['propertyToBeRemoved'];
```

In case of `ctx.instance`

```
ctx.instance.unsetAttribute('propertyToBeRemoved')
```

This statement prevented the unwanted property in the context of hooks from being saved to database.

Comment: How to use this for nested objects? ex: 
`ctx.instance.foo.propertyToBeRemoved` and
`ctx.instance.bar[0].propertyToBeRemoved `